# will tcp_cork and tcp_nodelay helps in increasing the performance of scoket programming in c

Tags: c, sockets

I have a combination of small files and large files(8k  to 100 gb) files in my filesystem.I need to transfer them using socket programming in c over a network of 1GB with 4 sockets to use much of network .

I have set the options tcp_cork and tcp_nodelay to improve the performance(MB/s).But I couldn't see significant difference whether I set those options or not.
In which scenario these two options will be useful .Is the chunk that we transfer mattes really.

Comment: You can visualize the defference after reading this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761276/when-should-i-use-tcp-nodelay-and-when-tcp-cork

Answer (score 0):

`TCP_NODELAY` might help, as it will enable `Linux` to send subsequent packets right away instead of waiting for `ACK`s.

However, this problem has been solved before, and any modern FTP or HTTP server would provide something close to the best achievable transfer throughput.