# why does an HTTP request request is sent after the first ack packet?

Tags: linux, sockets, http, tcp, wget

I an simulating http client traffic with RAW socket.
I send a SYN packet then get the SYN-ACK from the server. 
Finally I send an ACK+request packet and waits for the response.
I noticed that when using wget or curl,
the first ACK and the request are sent in two different packets.
why is that, and is that relevant to anything?

Comment: I think your question is being answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761276/when-should-i-use-tcp-nodelay-and-when-tcp-cork)

Comment: It is because that is the way they work, and no it isn't relevant to anything.

Answer (score 1):

A client application that uses a TCP socket typically calls socket() then connect() then send().  The connect() function establishes the TCP connection, and to do this the TCP protocol requires 3 packets: SYN, SYN+ACK, ACK.  After that the send() call sends the first data.  Therefore the ACK and data are sent separately.

I think your packet flow probably does satisfy the TCP protocol (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793), but it is unusual.